# local variable 'sampled_df' referenced before assignment

Tags: python

There is no return value because there is something wrong with the loop.
[image]

If the data type of the data frame column is categorized, I want to do stratififed sampling , and if there is no categorical type and the length of the value_counts is less than 5, I want to do stratified sampling. and if it is neither, I want to do simple random sampling.
this is my code.
`

```
tmpdf = pd.DataFrame(data=[[1,2,3,4,5],[2,3,4,5,6],[3,4,5,6,7],[4,5,6,7,8],[5,6,7,8,9]],columns=['a','b','c','d','e'])

def a(df):
    file_size = 2
    for col in df.columns[::-1]:
        if df[col].dtype in ('object','category'):
            if len(df[col].value_counts()) == 1:
                continue
            elif len(df[col].value_counts()[df[col].value_counts() == 1]) /len(df) > 0.05:
                continue
            elif df[col].isna().sum()/ len(df) > 0.1:
                continue
            sampled_df = df.groupby(col, group_keys=False).apply(lambda x:x if len(x) < 2 else x.sample(int(len(x)*(1/file_size))))
        elif len(df[col].value_counts()) >= 5:
            if len(df[col].value_counts()) == 1:
                continue
            elif len(df[col].value_counts()[df[col].value_counts() == 1]) /len(df) > 0.05:
                continue
            elif df[col].isna().sum()/ len(df) > 0.1:
                continue
            sampled_df = df.groupby(col, group_keys=False).apply(lambda x:x if len(x) < 2 else x.sample(int(len(x)*(1/file_size))))
        else:
            sampled_df = df.sample(frac = 1/file_size, random_state=2022,ignore_index=True)
        break

    sampled_df = sampled_df.reset_index(drop=True)    
    return sampled_df
```

`

Comment: Hello, please provide full error stacktrace. Also, do you call your function with same tmpdf? There may be reference before assignment if df.columns is empty

Comment: i edited with pictures. thank you

Answer (score 0):

All your iterations are continued due to

```
elif len(df[col].value_counts()[df[col].value_counts() == 1]) /len(df) > 0.05:
```

being `True` for each col. That's why `sampled_df` is not set at the end, and that's why you get referencing before assignment